# Getting to know the information about the published images

Tags: sitecore

I'm trying to find a way to find out which added images have Alt and description fields filled.
I'm trying to query the master database directly like this :

```
USE Fanuc2014_Web;

With EmptyValuedAltFields
AS 
( 
    SELECT I.Name,I.ID, F.Language, F.Value 
    FROM Items I
    INNER JOIN
        Fields F ON I.ID = F.ItemId
    WHERE 
        I.TemplateID = '{DAF085E8-602E-43A6-8299-038FF171349F}' AND F.FieldId = '{65885C44-8FCD-4A7F-94F1-EE63703FE193}' AND f.Value = ''
)

Select * FROM EmptyValuedAltFields
```

but I'm not getting the proper result. Is there anyway other than querying db or I need to tweak this query for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT I.Name,I.ID
    FROM Items I

    WHERE 
  (I.TemplateID = '{DAF085E8-602E-43A6-8299-038FF171349F}' OR i.TemplateID = '{F1828A2C-7E5D-4BBD-98CA-320474871548}')
  AND 0 = 
  (
   SELECT 
    COUNT(*) FROM Items II INNER JOIN Fields FD ON I.ID = FD.ItemId 
    WHERE
     (FD.FieldId = '{65885C44-8FCD-4A7F-94F1-EE63703FE193}' OR FD.FieldId = '{65885C44-8FCD-4A7F-94F1-EE63703FE193}')
     AND i.ID = ii.id
     AND fd.Value != ''
  )
```